# Sum of two squares equal to $2018^{2019}+2018$

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

$$x^2+y^2 = 2018^{2019}+2018$$

is expressed as sum of two perfect squares.

Any pair of perfect squares can satisfy?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What do you mean by "any set of perfect squares can fit into this expression"?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I still do not understand what the question is.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche It's [not our responsibility](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11189/290189) to find this out.  However, if you know that it is a contest question (see the [criteria](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16775/290189)), it's better to flag it for moderator's attention, so that they can [lock/delete the question](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27149/290189) until the deadline passes.  Note that it's *not* against any rule to post a contest questions.

Answer (score 4):

See that your expression equals $2018(2018^{2018}+1).$  If you can do two things, you can solve your problem:

1. Express $2018$ as a sum of two squares.
2. Convert the product of two sums of two squares into one sum of two squares.

Answer (score 4):

Since $1009$ is prime and $1009 \equiv 1 \mod 4,$ $1009$ can be expressed as a sum of two squares. $2=1^2+1^2.$ $2018^{2018}+1=(2018^{1009})^2+1^2.$
From these, you can conclude that $2 \times 1009 \times (2018^{2018}+1)$ is a sum of two squares. (I leave to you as an exercise to prove that the product of a sum of two squares is also a sum of two squares.)